# How do you ng-repeat through an object of objects to show key and value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, key-value

I have an object called "profile" that includes a handful of other objects -- each one I want to display the label followed by the display_value:

[image]

In my HTML, I know I need to ng-repeat through the object profile, but have not been able to get the desired display of label: display_value (i.e. Employment Start Date: 11/20/2019).  What is the correct syntax to loop through c.profile and display label followed by display_value?  Do I need two ng-repeats in this instance?

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in c.profile track by $index">
  {{item.?}}:  {{item.?}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in c.profile track by $index">
  {{item.label}}:  {{item.display_value}}
</div>
```

make sure your data is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"`:

```
<div ng-repeat="(category, valueObj) in c.profile">
    <h2>{{category}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in valueObj">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Iterating over object properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)